# Передвижение элементов формы C++

Tags: c#, c++

Задача:
Нужно реализовать движение контрола button1 из одного значения x, в дорогое

В C# делается так:

```
button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X + 5, button1.Location.Y) ;
```

А как в C++?

Comment: А в С++ зависит от используемой библиотеки. Нет в стандартном С++ никаких контролов...

Comment: это про winforms вопрос?

Comment: Вас жестоко обманули. Вы явно пишете код на C++/CLI и радуетесь, что изучаете кресты. Но это не так. Это два разных языка. И вы учите не то, что нужно.

Comment: Ну так вы предоставите дополнительную информацию? Вы используете C++ или C++/CLI? Какую GUI-библиотеку вы используете в C++? WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о WinAPI то используйте [`MoveWindow()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow)